# laravel no timeout setting for logged users

Tags: laravel, timeout, logout

Just want to know if it is possible to set the no timeout for logged in user.

Because I had created 2 accounts, and always 1 of the account would get page has been expired and I would need to re login again. Or is there any other suggestion for this problem?

Comment: what do you mean ? are you logging in two different account in the same browser ?

Comment: 2 different accounts on different places but same network,example 1 on laptop while another on mobile device, currently using this in command prompt to do it, php artisan serve --host 10.0.0.123 --port 80

Comment: the default session expiration is 2hrs .. you need to configure that in the app config ..

Comment: Yup I saw that but it just automatically expire for 1 hour for some reason sometimes, so I was wondering if I could just make it stay without session expiring

Comment: first you may want to know how the session works. i've encountered that error and found out that my browser haven't storing cookies that causing the session to expire before 2hrs.

Comment: another solution is have your system a lock out page where it refresh every 30mins .. it resets the session lifetime ..

Comment: May I know how you do the reset session part, if possible could you give me a link to it and also some tips or examples

Comment: every time you load a route or rather a page in your system .. the session lifetime is reset .. so what i basically have done is , in every page i have, there is a meta tag which redirect to a lockpage within 30mins. in that lockpage, it also refresh every 30mins. also, i require logged user that has been locked out to re-enter their password. but that was my approach, the important thing is, you refresh your page, or don't be idled in a single page(no ajax or no new request in the server) for 30mins.

Comment: Ohh i see i see, will try it out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the auth function there is a remeber possibility

```
Auth::attempt(['email' => $email, 'password' => $password], true))
```

By setting the last params as true now the user will me remember and won't logout until he does so

Comment: Thank you for replying, may i know where should I put this under?

Comment: you can put it in ur auth controller

Comment: The auth controller side contain, loginController, ForgotPasswordController, registerController and resetPasswordController. So am I suppose to put that inside there?

Comment: this should be in loginController

Comment: if you are using default loginController you should overwrite it and use this [Manually Authenticating Users](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/authentication#authenticating-users)